# SELECT dentro do INSERT PHP Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO TB004_PRODUTO_FORNECEDOR ( TB002_CODIGO, TB003_CODIGO )     
                  SELECT TB003_CODIGO, 1 AS Codigo FROM TB003_PRODUTO WHERE TB003_DESCRICAO = '$name_02'
                  VALUES ( '$name_01', Codigo )");
```

Como eu posso selecionar o código do produto dentro insert para ele apenas inserir o código?

Comment: Se isso for possivel, vou gostar de saber.. rsrs. Só não use mais o `mysql_*`, pois está defasado. Utilize o `mysqli_*` ou `PDO`

Comment: @AndreiCoelho eu já fiz no `PDO`, mas neste caso não posso, por mais que eu queria, vou ter que fazer `msql` mesmo.

Comment: Entendi =)... a resposta abaixo parece valida

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Olá, não sei se entendi bem, mas pelo que eu entendi você quer inserir o resultado de um select. Se for isso basta fazer +- assim:

```
INSERT INTO TB004_PRODUTO_FORNECEDOR ( TB002_CODIGO, TB003_CODIGO )     
VALUES ('$name_01',(SELECT TB003_CODIGO FROM TB003_PRODUTO WHERE TB003_DESCRICAO = '$name_02'))
```

Comment: Colocar o segundo valor em um select é isso? Legal.. vivendo e aprendendo

Comment: Olá se você quer inserir o segundo valor (TB003_CODIGO), mas só tem o nome para pesquisar então seria assim mesmo.

Comment: Entendi. Interessante...

Comment: Pior que tinha feito isso, mas outra coisa estava errada e não deu certo, eu segui o jeito que tinha feito no PDO `$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO tasks (Project, CompanyFantasy, Priorities, Delivery, Attachment, ByUser, Systems, OrderTask, Subject) VALUES 
                                    (:project, :companyfantasy, :priorities, :delivery, :attachment, :byuser, :systems, (select OrderTask from (SELECT MAX(OrderTask)+1 as OrderTask FROM tasks) X), :subject)");`, um pouco diferente a lógica porque estou usando MAX()+1.